# Ploting density function over histogram of random generated values from normal distribution

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to generate 100 random data(s) from normal distribution, create histogram of it and put density function over the histogram.

So far i have created

```
set.seed(123)
rs <- rnorm(100, mean = weighted.mean(femals$Salary), sd = sd(femals$Salary))
h <- hist(rs, col = "lightgray" , density = 50 )
xfit <- seq(min(femals$Salary), max(femals$Salary), length = 40) 
yfit <- dnorm(xfit, mean = mean(femals$Salary), sd = sd(femals$Salary)) 
yfit <- yfit * diff(h$mids[1:2]) * length(femals$Salary)
lines(xfit, yfit, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

The result of this is

[image]

However i am unsure if this is correct. Isnt density function way to low for that histogram? Shouldnt density follow the edges of histogram? Is this correct or did i make mistake in my code?

the mean and standard deviaton are:

```
weighted mean(femals$Salary) =  5138.852
sed(femals$Salary) = 539.8707
```

Comment: I think it's ok. The density, when I used it, never followed the histogram bar edges.

Comment: You didn't really make any mistakes. Since histograms and densities are by definition at very different scales, you are scaling the density up to get it close to the histogram to make it look the same. You can adjust more if you'd like since it's all arbitrary anyway.

Comment: You can also try: `library(tidyverse) ; 
as.data.frame(rs) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=rs,y=..density..)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 500) +
  geom_density(color=2)  `